# Unexpected plot when using geom_area to plot multiple stacked levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `geom_area` to make a plot that shows binned time series with multiple stacked levels (the bins are 15 minutes long each). The resulting plot seems to have some sort of glitch. I expect the areas for the different levels to be stacked, but instead there is a diagonal red line (corresponding to level 'g') that crosses the plot (see image). At t = 16:10:00 I would expect to see some blue area (corresponding to level 'v'). Instead there is just an empty triangle.

[image]

In addition to that issue, the time series contain a gap:

```
17: "2017-07-23 21:10:00"      t  3611
18: "2017-07-24 01:25:00"      t  6676
```

There are no events between these two times, so I would expect the area to be zero until t = 01:25:00. Instead, the plot shows a linear slope starting at (21:10:00, 3611) and ending at (01:25:00, 6676). I suppose this might be fixed if I add the missing intervals in the gap and set them to zero. But, I wonder if there is any easier way to do so.

I am using R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) and ggplot2 version 2.2.1.

The following example should reproduce the issues:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

txt <- 'time requester count
1: "2017-07-23 17:40:00"      t  6289
2: "2017-07-23 17:55:00"      t  7161
3: "2017-07-23 18:10:00"      t  7444
4: "2017-07-23 18:25:00"      t  7121
5: "2017-07-23 18:40:00"      t  6677
6: "2017-07-23 18:55:00"      t  6604
7: "2017-07-23 19:10:00"      t  7079
8: "2017-07-23 19:25:00"      t  6856
9: "2017-07-23 19:40:00"      t  6663
10: "2017-07-23 19:55:00"      t  6829
11: "2017-07-23 20:10:00"      t  6945
12: "2017-07-23 20:25:00"      t  6876
13: "2017-07-23 20:25:00"      g     5
14: "2017-07-23 20:40:00"      t  7087
15: "2017-07-23 20:40:00"      g     1
16: "2017-07-23 20:55:00"      t  6752
17: "2017-07-23 21:10:00"      t  3611
18: "2017-07-24 01:25:00"      t  6676
19: "2017-07-24 01:40:00"      t  7100
20: "2017-07-24 01:55:00"      t  7192
21: "2017-07-24 02:10:00"      t  7640
22: "2017-07-24 02:25:00"      t  7543
23: "2017-07-24 02:40:00"      t  7289
24: "2017-07-24 02:55:00"      t  7170
25: "2017-07-24 03:10:00"      t  7022
26: "2017-07-24 03:25:00"      t  7524
27: "2017-07-24 03:40:00"      t  7285
28: "2017-07-24 03:55:00"      t  6834
29: "2017-07-24 04:10:00"      t  6035
30: "2017-07-24 04:25:00"      t  7055
31: "2017-07-24 04:40:00"      t  6072
32: "2017-07-24 04:55:00"      t  5737
33: "2017-07-24 05:10:00"      t  5847
34: "2017-07-24 05:25:00"      t  5838
35: "2017-07-24 05:40:00"      t  5282
36: "2017-07-24 05:55:00"      t  5467
37: "2017-07-24 06:10:00"      t  5502
38: "2017-07-24 06:25:00"      t  5328
39: "2017-07-24 06:40:00"      t  4752
40: "2017-07-24 06:55:00"      t  4720
41: "2017-07-24 07:10:00"      t  3994
42: "2017-07-24 07:25:00"      t  3926
43: "2017-07-24 07:40:00"      t  3003
44: "2017-07-24 07:55:00"      t  3183
45: "2017-07-24 08:10:00"      t  3155
46: "2017-07-24 08:25:00"      t  3642
47: "2017-07-24 08:40:00"      t  4251
48: "2017-07-24 08:55:00"      t  4064
49: "2017-07-24 09:10:00"      t  4032
50: "2017-07-24 09:25:00"      t  3722
51: "2017-07-24 09:40:00"      t  3897
52: "2017-07-24 09:55:00"      t  4351
53: "2017-07-24 10:10:00"      t  4655
54: "2017-07-24 10:25:00"      t  4676
55: "2017-07-24 10:40:00"      t  4961
56: "2017-07-24 10:55:00"      t  4669
57: "2017-07-24 11:10:00"      t  4426
58: "2017-07-24 11:10:00"      g    13
59: "2017-07-24 11:25:00"      t  5387
60: "2017-07-24 11:40:00"      t  5323
61: "2017-07-24 11:55:00"      t  4818
62: "2017-07-24 12:10:00"      t  4554
63: "2017-07-24 12:10:00"      g     6
64: "2017-07-24 12:25:00"      t  5000
65: "2017-07-24 12:40:00"      t  4597
66: "2017-07-24 12:55:00"      t  5196
67: "2017-07-24 12:55:00"      g     2
68: "2017-07-24 13:10:00"      t  4964
69: "2017-07-24 13:10:00"      g     2
70: "2017-07-24 13:25:00"      t  4922
71: "2017-07-24 13:25:00"      g     2
72: "2017-07-24 13:40:00"      t  4843
73: "2017-07-24 13:55:00"      t  4803
74: "2017-07-24 13:55:00"      g    50
75: "2017-07-24 14:10:00"      t  4828
76: "2017-07-24 14:25:00"      t  4750
77: "2017-07-24 14:25:00"      g     1
78: "2017-07-24 14:40:00"      t  4873
79: "2017-07-24 14:40:00"      g     3
80: "2017-07-24 14:55:00"      t  4679
81: "2017-07-24 15:10:00"      t  5262
82: "2017-07-24 15:10:00"      g    17
83: "2017-07-24 15:25:00"      t  5396
84: "2017-07-24 15:25:00"      g    59
85: "2017-07-24 15:40:00"      t  5312
86: "2017-07-24 15:55:00"      t  5171
87: "2017-07-24 16:10:00"      t  5570
88: "2017-07-24 16:10:00"      v    48
89: "2017-07-24 16:25:00"      t  5606
90: "2017-07-24 16:40:00"      t  5041
91: "2017-07-24 16:40:00"      g    20
92: "2017-07-24 16:55:00"      t  5292
93: "2017-07-24 16:55:00"      g    12
94: "2017-07-24 17:10:00"      t  5233
95: "2017-07-24 17:10:00"      g     2
96: "2017-07-24 17:25:00"      t  5355
97: "2017-07-24 17:25:00"      g    24
98: "2017-07-24 17:40:00"      t   316
99: "2017-07-24 17:40:00"      g     9'

dt <- data.table(read.table(text=txt, header=T))
dt[, time := as.POSIXct(time, tz='UTC')]

pl <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = time, y = count)) +
  geom_area(stat = 'identity', aes(fill = requester))
print(pl)
```

Comment: For me, `geom_area` is just filling the area below a `geom_line`. Try using `ggplot(dt, aes(x = time, y = count)) + geom_line(aes(color = requester), lwd = 2)` to see what your plot should look like if using lines.

Comment: @F.Privé If I do that, the red line appears at the bottom and it seems to make sense. There is no trace of any blue line, though. And the issue about no "respecting" the gap is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your data you have one value per row. For the stacked area plot, however, you need information for all three requester types per row, even if it is zero.
For that purpose, you need to reshape your data to create 0 where no count is available.
This code included the 'reshape' part will create the stacked area graph:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# insert your data as above


dt <- data.table(read.table(text=txt, header=T))
dt[, time := as.POSIXct(time, tz='UTC')]

####### NEW: Reshaping ########
#reshape your data from long to wide format
data_wide <- dcast(dt, time ~ requester, value.var="count") 
data_wide[is.na(data_wide)] <- 0 #replace all NA with 0

#reshape your long data included 0 back to wide format
data_long <- melt(data_wide, id.vars = c("time"),
              variable.name = "requester", 
              value.name = "count")
##############################

# produce the stacked area graph
pl <- ggplot(data_long, aes(x = time, y=count)) +
      geom_area(stat = 'identity', aes(fill = requester))
print(pl)
```

Regarding the gap in your data, I assume you need to include those rows with the time data in your data frame and fill the corresponding count values with 0.

Comment: In the end I used a slightly different approach, but very close to your solution. I also added the following code before the call to `melt`: `data_wide <- data_wide %>% pad(interval = "15 mins") %>% fill_by_value()`. That line uses the `dplyr` and `padr` packages to create all the missing intervals, fixing the gap problem. Please, feel free to update your answer with that extra line to have a solution that fixes the gap issue too. Thanks!